# Getting the error “Cannot read property 'top' of undefined”

Tags: jquery

I understand that this error means that I am potentially performing an action on an undefined Jquery variable, but I feel as though I've gone through all the necessary steps to avoid this error by checking if the value exists and making sure the length is greater then 0. I have a form that submits data to a database, and when I click the submit button, I get this error on the console (data is still getting sent to db)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    });
});

$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#BSDOMAddEditEntryModal', function () {    
    if (!$('#BSDOMAddEditEntryModal').hasClass('show') && !$('#BSDOMAddEditEntryModal').hasClass('in')) {
        $(".modal-backdrop.fade.in").remove();
        $(".modal-backdrop.fade.show").remove();
    }

    $('.BSDOMInputGrpCalendarIcon').datepicker({
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        autoclose: true
    }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
        $(this).parent().find('input:text').val(e.format());
    });
});

function validateBSDOMChkBxL(source, args) {
    if ($("[id$='" + source.id + "']").siblings('div').find('table input:checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else{
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}

function confirmDeleteReportBtn() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?") == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function CheckboxErrorVal(source) {
    if ($("[id$='" + source.id + "']").find('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
        $("[id$='" + source.id + "']").parent().siblings('span').css("display", "none");
    } 
    else 
    {
        $("[id$='" + source.id + "']").parent().siblings('span').css("display", "inline");
    }
}

function BSDOMFileUploadComplete() {
    //Postback is necessary for asyncfileupload
    var id = $("[id$='_DvFileUploadPanel']").attr('id');
    updateUploadStatus("success", "File Uploaded Successfully");

    __doPostBack(id, '');
}

function BSDOMFileUploadStart(sender, args) {
    var fileName = args.get_fileName();
    var fileExt = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    if (fileExt == "xls" || fileExt == "xlsx" || fileExt == "pdf" || fileExt == "xml" || fileExt == "doc" || fileExt == "docx" || fileExt == "jpeg" || fileExt == "jpg" || fileExt == "png") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        //To cancel the upload, throw an error, it will fire OnClientUploadError
        var err = new Error();
        err.name = "Upload Error";
        err.message = "*Only accept format in xls, xlsx, pdf, doc, docx, jpeg, jpg, png";
        throw (err);

        return false;
    }
}
function BSDOMFileUploadError(sender, args) {
        var errmsg = args.get_errorMessage();
        updateUploadStatus("error", errmsg);
    }

function updateUploadStatus(status, message) {
        var uploadstatlbl = $("span[id$='lblUploadStatus']");
        uploadstatlbl.html(message);
        if (status == "error") {
            uploadstatlbl.removeClass("BSDOMFileUploadSuccess").addClass("BSDOMFileUploadError invalidMsgCss");
        } else {
            uploadstatlbl.removeClass("BSDOMFileUploadError invalidMsgCss").addClass("BSDOMFileUploadSuccess");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide the specific code that is causing the error (none of your code at present appears to be checking for top on any element)?

Comment: That's a lot of code--perhaps you should try to narrow it down to where it fails, like by looking at the stack trace?

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you run code in `document.ready` which then runs code on `document.ready`? That seems redundant. `confirmDeleteReportBtn` is... *very* redundant (and similar redundancies exist elsewhere). Things like `("[id$='" + source.id + "']"` should be extracted out into a variable. Functions like `CheckboxErrorVal` that only set a string should just set that string then make the call instead of duplicating all the code. There's more, but I'm nearly out of space.

Comment: This is the rror that gets highlighted in the console: var scrollTop = $('#dnn_ctr419_ctl00_dnnSkinMessage').offset().top - parseInt($(document.body).css("margin-top"));

Comment: Then you should update you question with the actual pertinent code. None of what is in your question matches the error. You also should do your error checking on that line as apparently there isn't an element at that time with id `dnn_ctr419_ctl00_dnnSkinMessage`